# Limit of $n^2\int^1_0\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I tried applying the mean value theorem for integrals here to find the limit but couldn't see what $f$ and $g$ (as in the theorem) should be. I also tried estimating $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ with other functions but couldn't find suitable ones to sandwich in between.

Comment: I think Laplace's method should show $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi/n}$ as $n\to \infty$; so that would imply your limit is $\infty$.

Comment: I am not familiar with that, can you please tell me what it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: @VeDAN Can you explain how you got this inequality? After plotting the graph, it appears that the inequality doesn't always hold.

Comment: @aritracb I need to look into it further - I made an algebra mistake so will retry it - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n }.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306819/evaluate-the-limit-of-the-following-sequence)